# Browsers behavior for showing previously entered values

Tags: browser, webbrowser-control, cross-browser, browser-cache

I have couple of JSP pages in my application with couple of "input" tags of type "text"

What I observed is, in Chrome, if the text field is in a "form" tag and if there is a form submission and when user comes back to the same page and tries click down arrow, it shows previously entered value.
 But if there is no form submission, that is page transition happens with AJAX call, chrome is not showing this previously entered value.

But in IE and Firefox it is not the case, I mean it is not showing the previous value that user entered before even with form submission.

My questions are:
1. How Chrome is showing previously entered value only when "input" tag is in "form" and with form submission?

2.Why IE and Firefox is not showing previously entered values. Do I need to do any settings in these browsers to show previuosly entered value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The feature that you are referring to is Autofill.  You can access additional details on it at: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142893
- IE: Go to Internet Explorer Menu/Tools/Options/Content/AutoComplete/
  click Settings > Check the options that you want.
- Firefox:
  http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Form%20autocomplete;